# Continuous time-dependent signal prediction

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, prediction

Which type of artificial neural network would you suggest to be able to make **continuous time-dependant signal predictions**? It should predict smallscale steps over very few signals up to very large scale steps with very many signals, possibly with less precision (abstraction by some kind of hierarchy?).

See:
[image]

Actually the system should learn and predict simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I think a Spiking Neural Network, which is "third generation" and most similar to the neurons in our brain would do best.

It runs in real time, although I don't think it can learn in real-time.

Instead, you can just continually examine and overhaul it, running a couple seconds behind live input so you can adjust its answers, before it becomes good enough to go real-time.

Comment: I already considered this as my neuron-model. As far as I know, there are learning algorithms, that enable real-time learning. Although I'm still unsure about the architecture. I've never worked with (hierarchical)recurrent networks and don't get how to use them for prediction. The feedback would be used as the predicting part, but I don't know how to alter it's weight right

Comment: Sadly, I've never had much luck with neural networks, so I don't know the learning algorithms. Most of them take math I'm not yet familiar with.